# Using `this` with object literals

Tags: javascript

I thought I know JavaScript, it seems I don't.

I want to define an object like this. (Example from http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/ )

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
}
```

Well, this looks fine, let's print the info...

```
apple.getInfo() //returns "red macintosh apple" as expected
```

OK, now take the function out and run it again...

```
var func = apple.getInfo; func(); //returns "undefined undefined apple"
```

Well, that is not what I expected. Apparently, `this` is interpreted as `window`. Which is not what I wanted.

My question is -- what is the idiomatic, preferred way to rewrite the `apple` literal, so that `apple.getInfo` returns a function, that could be run separately, but still used the object properties?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `this` works is that it depends on how it is called. A quick tip to know what `this` is is to look at the object before the function name in the call.

Doing `apple.getInfo()` makes `this` refer to `apple`. But calling it as `func()` is as if calling `window.func()` (assuming it's in the global space), which makes `this` refer to `window`.

If you want to "force" the value of `this` on a function, then do `bind`. It creates a copy of the function with `this` forced as the first parameter passed.

```
var func = apple.getInfo.bind(apple);
// all calls to `func` will have `this` "forced" as `apple`
```

If you want to dictate `this` on the call but not permanently tamper `this` on `func` (like how `bind` does it), you can go with `call` or `apply`:

```
var func = apple.getInfo;
func.call(apple);
func.apply(apple);
// Both function will have `this` as `apple` only for the call.
```

Comment: Hm, interesting! I didn't know it is this complex. I needed a function to call to give as a callback, I thought I could just use `apple.getInfo` and not create anonymous functions. OK, I will then just make another anonymous function then. Thank you!

Comment: Addendum: I actually ended up using .bind instead of anonymous function, because it just "seems" cleaner. (Not sure if it's faster/more efficient, or not.)

Comment: Huh, I was wrong! The closure is *really* more efficient than binding - on all browsers. http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-self-closure/7

Answer (score 1):

@Joseph The Dreamer has put up a great answer.

Since the OP is looking for a way to have `apple.getInfo` always return a function that doesn't have the `undefined` problem, I figured I'd throw up this alternative.

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red"
};

apple.getInfo = (function () {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
}).bind( apple );
```

This way you don't have to call `apple.getInfo.bind(apple)` every time you want to create a new reference to the function.

Note that you can't put `getInfo` within the original object literal because at that point, `apple` doesn't have a value assigned to it and `.bind( apple )` won't work properly.